# PHP как правельно вывесни данные из ячейки БД после выборки строки

Tags: php, sql

Выбираю пользователя из таблицы users где mail равен введенному mail-у пользователя

```html
$sql = mysqli_prepare($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE mail = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, 's', $mail);
mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
```

Далее хочу вывести имя этого пользователя,

```html
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['name'];
```

Выводится ошибка:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_stmt_get_result()

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема? PHP только начал изучать.

Comment: Сделайте как в примере http://www.php.su/functions/?mysqli-prepare

Answer (score 0):

для работы этой функции нужен установленный mysqlnd драйвер.
скорее всего в вашей системе он не стоит
либо установите его либо используйте две функции mysqli_stmt_bind_result и mysqli_stmt_fetch

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php